# Storybook: Object is not a function on Twig Component

Tags: javascript, twig, components, storybook

I am trying to import a component into a component story using storybook.

The component is written in twig. The storybook template uses js. I am adapting the component to use controls instead of knobs which storybook no longer uses.

I get an error "Object is not a function" - and not much else as help. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I know Twig rendering is working correctly with other components.

**My Story**

```
// Your Twig component
import { createInput } from '../components/input.twig';
import Faker from 'faker'

// Generate data with Faker
const fullName = Faker.name.findName()
const fullNameEg = Faker.name.findName()

export default {
  title: 'Elements/Input',
  argTypes: {
    label: { control: 'text' },
    value: { control: 'text' },
    placeholder: { control: 'text' },
    error: { control: 'text' },
    isDisabled: { control: 'boolean' },
    isRequired: { control: 'boolean' },
  },
};

const Template = ({ label, ...args }) => {
  // You can either use a function to create DOM elements or use a plain html string!
  // return `<div>${label}</div>`;
  return createInput({ label, ...args });
};

export const Filled = Template.bind({});
Filled.args = {
    label: 'First name',
    value: fullName,
    error: '',
    placeholder: `Eg: ${fullNameEg}`,
    isDisabled: false,
    isRequired: false,
};

export const Empty = Template.bind({});
Empty.args = {
    label: 'First name',
    value: '',
    error: '',
    placeholder: `Eg: ${fullNameEg}`,
    isDisabled: false,
    isRequired: false,
};

export const Disabled = Template.bind({});
Disabled.args = {
    label: 'First name',
    value: fullName,
    error: '',
    placeholder: `Eg: ${fullNameEg}`,
    isDisabled: true,
    isRequired: false,
};

export const Required = Template.bind({});
Required.args = {
    label: 'First name',
    value: fullName,
    error: '',
    placeholder: `Eg: ${fullNameEg}`,
    isDisabled: false,
    isRequired: true,
};

export const Error = Template.bind({});
Error.args = {
    label: 'First name',
    value: fullName,
    error: 'Sorry, that’s a poor name. Try another.',
    placeholder: `Eg: ${fullNameEg}`,
    isDisabled: false,
    isRequired: false,
};
```

**My Component**

```
{#
Accessible input demo
Usage example:
{% include "components/input" with {
    label: "Enter your greeting",
    value: "Hi there Crafter",
    error: "",
    isDisabled: false,
    isRequired: false,
    placeholder: "Eg: Go get crafty!",
} %}
#}

<div class="input {{ error ? 'input-has-error' }}{{ isDisabled|default ? ' input-is-disabled' }}">
    <label for="input-field" class="input-label">
        {{ label|default }}
        {% if isRequired|default %}
            <span class="input-required">
                *</span>
        {% endif %}
    </label>
    <input id="input-field" class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-grey-darker" value="{{ value }}" type="text" {{ placeholder|default ? ' placeholder="' ~ placeholder ~ '"' }} {{ error|default|length > 0 ? ' aria-invalid="true"' }} {{ error|default ? ' aria-describedby="input-error-message"' }} {{ isDisabled|default ? ' disabled' }} {{ isRequired|default ? ' required' }}/>
    {% if error|default %}
        <div id="input-error-message" class="input-error-message">{{ error }}</div>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

**Original Story I am adapting**

```
// Learn more about the knobs addon:
// https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/blob/master/addons/knobs/README.md
import { text, boolean, number } from '@storybook/addon-knobs'
// Faker creates random data for your components
// https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/#api-methods
import Faker from 'faker'

// Your Twig component
import component from '../components/input.twig'

const container = children => {
    // Font-size slider for component resizing
    // (Use ems in your component styles)
    const scale = number('scale', 1, {
        range: true,
        min: 1,
        max: 2.5,
        step: 0.25,
    })
    return `<div style="font-size:${scale}em">${children}</div>`
}

// Generate data with Faker
// https://github.com/marak/Faker.js/#api-methods
const fullName = Faker.name.findName()
const fullNameEg = Faker.name.findName()

// Set the component name
export default { title: 'Input' }

export const filled = () =>
    container(
        component({
            label: text('label', 'Full name'),
            value: text('value', fullName),
            error: text('error', ''),
            isDisabled: boolean('isDisabled', false),
            isRequired: boolean('isRequired', false),
            placeholder: text('placeholder', `Eg: ${fullNameEg}`),
        })
    )

export const empty = () =>
    container(
        component({
            label: text('label', 'Full name'),
            value: text('value', ''),
            error: text('error', ''),
            isDisabled: boolean('isDisabled', false),
            isRequired: boolean('isRequired', false),
            placeholder: text('placeholder', `Eg: ${fullNameEg}`),
        })
    )

export const disabled = () =>
    container(
        component({
            label: text('label', 'Full name'),
            value: text('value', fullName),
            error: text('error', ''),
            isDisabled: boolean('isDisabled', true),
            isRequired: boolean('isRequired', false),
            placeholder: text('placeholder', `Eg: ${fullNameEg}`),
        })
    )

export const required = () =>
    container(
        component({
            label: text('label', 'Full name'),
            value: text('value', fullName),
            error: text('error', ''),
            isDisabled: boolean('isDisabled', false),
            isRequired: boolean('isRequired', true),
            placeholder: text('placeholder', `Eg: ${fullNameEg}`),
        })
    )

export const error = () =>
    container(
        component({
            label: text('label', 'Full name'),
            value: text('value', fullName),
            error: text('error', 'Sorry, that’s a poor name. Try another.'),
            isDisabled: boolean('isDisabled', false),
            isRequired: boolean('isRequired', false),
            placeholder: text('placeholder', `Eg: ${fullNameEg}`),
        })
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of `sass-loader` isn’t supported yet so you’ll need to install an older version:

```sh
npm i -D sass-loader@10.1.1
```

[See the craft-storybook-starter for a working example →](https://github.com/ben-rogerson/craft-storybook-starter)